# Retrofit: How to decompress gzip before using GsonConverterFactory

Tags: android, retrofit

Thing goes ok before I add `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`
before:

```kotlin
val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(client)
    .baseUrl("http://")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build()
```

After, I added an interceptor into client:

```kotlin
.addInterceptor(Interceptor { chain ->
    val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
        .build()
    return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
})
```

Then the GsonConverterFactory works wrong.

---

Some people say 'okHttp is "smart enough" to know that and decompress it', but I can't find out where is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to add the `Accept-Encoding` header manually. Try removing the interceptor and OkHttp will manage that:

```kotlin
val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(client)
    .baseUrl("http://...")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build()
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw this answer in other place. But I want to know how to solve.